# How to Configure IIS Path for localhost

Tags: c#, .net, iis, localhost

Online, I don't have trouble! The root is the domain of the website!
On localhost, my folder (where I have all my websites) is, c:\localhost.

Well, now, for each site (let say, MarkWebsite01) I do a (static) function that will be included every time I put a photo/resource/etc... and get the path from web.config, such as :

```
<img src="<%=MyUtilities.GiveMePath%>/images/hello.gif" />
```

that means :

```
<img src="/MarkWebsite01/images/hello.gif" />
```

I'm really bored to putting this every time. Is there a strategy where I can configure (on localhost) my website? So I can avoid this for each website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's IIS Express run from Visual Studio / Web Developer Express then if you click on the top folder in solution explorer and open the properties pane (right click properties, or F4), in there you should see the `virtual path`. It's probably set as the root folder, rather than /MarkWebsite01/.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following option:
1. directly use online image, such as: http://online-domain/images/
2. use ../ to switch folder, such as: ../images/
3. use ~/, such as: ~/rootFolder/../images/